# Put Button at bottom of scrollview or bottom of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a problem with layout of my Application.

I'm trying to do a layout like Trello (screen of trello layout for example get from google)

[image]

**But I have a problem with the Button at the Bottom of ScrollView**:

Now my app is something like:

[image]

So How you can see, the button I always at the bottom of display.
I would like create a Header section, body section with Scrollview and recycler view and Footer with action button.

For now my xml app is:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView 
       xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
       android:id="@+id/card_view"
       android:layout_width="320dp"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
    >
       <RelativeLayout
          android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:orientation="vertical">
            <RelativeLayout
               android:id="@+id/header"
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/header_title"
                   style="@style/card_header_text"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                   android:orientation="vertical"
                   android:text="title"
               />
               <TextView
                   android:id="@+id/header_subtitle"
                   style="@style/card_header_text"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                   android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                   android:layout_below="@+id/header_title"
                   android:text="subtitle" />
              <ImageButton
                 android:id="@+id/context_menu"
                 android:layout_width="80dp"
                 android:layout_height="24dp"
                 android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                 android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                 android:layout_gravity="right"
                 android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                 android:clickable="true"
                 android:src="@drawable/ic_more_vert_black_16dp"
              />
           </RelativeLayout>
           <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
             android:layout_below="@+id/header"
             android:layout_above="@+id/button_action"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
                   android:id="@+id/list"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_below="@id/header"
                />
           </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
           <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_action"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:text="@string/button_action"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The parent Layout that contain a "list of block" is

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollFather"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
       android:orientation="horizontal"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
          android:id="@+id/list_blocks"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
       />
   </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

**EDIT**

I have tried to make a modify to my xml with:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
   android:id="@+id/myNestedScrollView"
   android:layout_below="@+id/header"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
      android:id="@+id/list"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   />
</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
<Button
   android:id="@+id/button_action"
   android:layout_below="@+id/myNestedScrollView"     <!-- as suggested -->
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"

   android:text="@string/button_action"
/>
```

But the problem now is the scrollview with recycler hides the Button:

[image]

How Can I replicate the layout ?

Comment: share the xml of the parent layout

Comment: what do you think `android:layout_alignParentBottom=true` does?

Comment: @SaravInfern I have shared the parent of List, it is a List of Lists

Comment: This is the behaviour of `android:layout_alignParentBottom=true` . For solution i think you should use a LinearLayout as `CardView` first child and set the `ScrollView` height at runtime as per content.

Comment: I believe the issue is because of the  recycler view's (list_blocks) layout height is `match parent` ,  change it to `wrap content`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
         android:id="@+id/myNestedScrollView"
         android:layout_below="@+id/header"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView 
               android:id="@+id/list"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
       </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

       <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_action"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/myNestedScrollView"
        android:text="@string/button_action"/>
```

Changes

Don't do alignParentBottom on Button and don't put NestedScrollView above Button instead put Button below NestedScrollView

And there is no need to use `android:layout_below="@id/header"` in RecyclerView

Comment: yes, But if the scrollview is "height" as display, the button never show

Comment: It should I think. Try this and let me know

Comment: I have tried but if the scrollview is height as much as the display it will hide the button, I'm updating my question with image and new code